# How to animate gradient moving up on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I want to mimic the "Want" iPhone app background, there are 3 colors that I want a view to cycle through, let us say red, blue, and green.

I want there to be a gradient with red to blue to green, each 1/3 of the screen, faded into each other (gradient), then, I want the red to go off screen on the top and come back on the bottom. (See photos below...)

The animation should move up, I want the gradient to go up and reform at the bottom of the screen and go up.

I tried using CAGradientLayer and animating the "colors" property, but that just looks like everything fades into each other, not necessarily moving off screen.

Contemplating  using OpenGL, but don't want to go that low for something that seems pretty simple. Any help/code samples would be much appreciated.  I basically need help animating a gradient using CoreAnimation/CoreGraphics.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Animating the `colors` property of a CAGradientLayer will just cause a fade, as you've discovered. However I think a gradient layer is the way to go. You should look at the following options:

- animating the `positions` property as well as / instead of the `colors`.
- creating a larger gradient layer that contains your full animation cycle and animating its position

The second option will probably give the best performance as the gradient will not need to be recalculated.

Comment: Ok, so I tried creating a gradient layer larger than the screen (3x the screen height), and animated its position.y, and it works, until the position.y > screen origin.y.  Do I create another gradient and place it under the first one so it just continues, how do you keep the animation going after the larger Gradient layer goes off screen? I think just creating a CAGradientLayer with a super long height and animating its position.y is not necessarily the answer, because it can still eventually end. I would like it to animate forever.

Comment: Well, when it gets to a loop point, you'd reset the position to the top (without animation) then loop again.

Comment: Worked like a charm. One comment- I needed to create 2 CAGradientLayers, one red-blue-red and the other red-blue-red as well. I placed one on top of the other (one on top and one starting at the end of the first), I animated the position.y of both until the first went off screen and the second was now at the origin of the first. I then moved the first one under the second with no animation, and animated the position.y again.  Thanks @jrtuton!

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass UIView to create a GradientView class. Add an array to hold the colors you are moving through. The choice is important and I [wrote an article](http://blog.karmadust.com/animating-a-gradient-in-a-uiview/) explaining why. Override the *drawRect(rect: CGRect)* method and interpolate between the components of the colors:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

   let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextSaveGState(context);

   let c1 = colors[index == 0 ? (colors.count - 1) : index - 1] // previous
   let c2 = colors[index]                                       // current
   let c3 = colors[index == (colors.count - 1) ? 0 : index + 1] // next

   var c1Comp = CGColorGetComponents(c1.CGColor)
   var c2Comp = CGColorGetComponents(c2.CGColor)
   var c3Comp = CGColorGetComponents(c3.CGColor)

   var colorComponents = [
       c1Comp[0] * (1 - factor) + c2Comp[0] * factor, // color 1 and 2
       c1Comp[1] * (1 - factor) + c2Comp[1] * factor,
       c1Comp[2] * (1 - factor) + c2Comp[2] * factor,
       c1Comp[3] * (1 - factor) + c2Comp[3] * factor,
       c2Comp[0] * (1 - factor) + c3Comp[0] * factor, // color 2 and 3
       c2Comp[1] * (1 - factor) + c3Comp[1] * factor,
       c2Comp[2] * (1 - factor) + c3Comp[2] * factor,
       c2Comp[3] * (1 - factor) + c3Comp[3] * factor    
   ]

   let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), &colorComponents, [0.0, 1.0], 2)

   let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
   let endPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.size.width, y: rect.size.height)
   CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsAfterEndLocation)

   CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

The index variable starts from 0 and wraps around the colors array while the factor is between 0.0 and 1.0 and animates through a timer:

```
var index: Int = 0
var factor: CGFloat = 1.0
var timer: NSTimer?

func animateToNextGradient() {
    index = (index + 1) % colors.count
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.factor = 0.0    
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0/60.0, target: self, selector: "animate:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func animate(timer: NSTimer) {
    self.factor += 0.02
    if(self.factor > 1.0) {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
    }
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to animate the gradient as required, I looked up your speedo app and the animation is brilliant, how did you achieve that if I may ?

Comment: I added a post after your question on my blog with some companion code. Please have a look if it is what you want http://karmadust.com/animating-a-gradient-in-a-uiview/

Comment: @MikeM That link no longer works, do you have another?

Comment: Here is the updated link http://blog.karmadust.com/animating-a-gradient-in-a-uiview/